# Why does the apt-key man page advise against using its add command?

Tags: apt

The [Ubuntu man page for apt-key](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/apt-key.8.html) includes the following note regarding `apt-key add`:

> Note: Instead of using this command a keyring should be placed
>   directly in the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ directory with a
>   descriptive name and either "gpg" or "asc" as file extension.

I don't think I've ever seen this advice anywhere else. Most projects that host their own repositories say to download their key file and add it with `apt-key`.

1. What is the motivation behind this advice?
2. Is this an Ubuntu-ism, or does it apply to any APT-based distro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the benefit of /etc/apt/sources.list.d over /etc/apt/sources.list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407328/what-is-the-benefit-of-etc-apt-sources-list-d-over-etc-apt-sources-list)

Comment: Not an _actual_ duplicate per se; but the underlying question (why use `.d` directories?) is the same.

Comment: It's not a duplicate at all, because the actual answer is _not to do_ with the desirability or otherwise of `.d` directories.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Those projects have outdated instructions.  I know this because I publish [a Debian repository](http://jdebp.info./Softwares/package-repositories.html) and I updated my instructions when I found out about the changes in Debian 9 APT.  Indeed, this part of the manual is now out of date, as it is the wrong directory.

This is not really to do with `.d` directories and more to do with preventing a cross-site vulnerability in APT.  The older system used separate keyring files for convenience, but this is now a necessity for security; *your* security.

This is the vulnerability.  Consider two repository publishers, A and B.  In the world of Debian 8 and before, both publishers' keys went in the single global keyring on users' machines.  If publisher A could somehow arrange to supplant the repository WWW site of publisher B, then A could publish subversive packages, *signed with A's own key*, which APT would happily accept and install.  A's key is, after all, trusted globally for all repositories.

The mitigation is for users to *use separate keyrings for individual publishers*, and to reference those keyrings with individual `Signed-By` settings in their repository definitions.  Specifically, publisher A's key is only used in the `Signed-By` of repository A and publisher B's key is only used in the `Signed-By` of repository B.  This way, if publisher A supplants publisher B's repository, APT will not accept the subversive packages from it since they and the repository are signed by publisher A's key not by publisher B's.

The `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` mechanism at hand is an older Poor Man's somewhat flawed halfway house towards this, from back in 2005 or so, that is not quite good enough.  It sets up the keyring in a separate file, so that it can be packaged up and just installed in one step by a package manager (or downloaded with `fetch`/`curl`/`wget`) as any other file.  (The package manager handles preventing publisher A's special *this-is-my-repository-keyring* package from installing over publisher B's, in the normal way that it handles file conflicts between packages in general.)  But it still adds it to the set of keys that is globally trusted for all repositories.  The full mechanism that exists now uses separate, *not* globally trusted, keyring files in `/usr/share/keyrings/`.

My instructions are already there.  ☺  There are moves afoot to move Debian's own repositories to this mechanism, so that they no longer use globally trusted keys either.  You might want to have a word with those "most projects" that you found.  After all, they are currently instructing you to hand over global access to APT on your machine to them.

## Further reading

- Daniel Kahn Gillmor (2017-05-02).  *[Please ship release-specific keys separately outside of `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=861695)*.  Debian bug #861695.
- Daniel Kahn Gillmor (2017-07-27).  *[debian `sources.list` entries should have signed-by options pointing to specific keys](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877012)*.  Debian bug #877012.
- ["Sources.list entry"](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Sources.list_entry). *Instructions to connect to a third-party repository*.  Debian wiki.  2018.
- [Why isn't it a security risk to add to sources.list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460525/)
- [Debian 9, APT, and "GPG error: ... InRelease: The following signatures were invalid:"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387053/)

Comment: IMO this answer should have MANY more upvotes! Obviously adding a third party repo always has some security implications, but let's keep the opportunity for bad things happening to a minimum eh?!

Comment: This article could be useful to those looking for step-by-step instructions to add a repository signing keyring https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html

Answer (score 1):

`apt-key del` takes the `keyid`, which is a meaningless hash of the key.

It is simpler if you can uninstall keys using a meaningful name... like a filename.

As JdeBP says, this works nicely with trusted key files that are installed as part of a debian package.  I think it can also be nicer when you've manually installed a key file.

In the new mechanism which is currently in "initial testing", this is further simplified.  You only have to remove/disable one thing: the *repository* (in sources.list / sources.list.d).  That will automatically stop allowing the key configured for that repo (unless it was also used by another repo).

I don't know how to take advantage of the new mechanism for security.  I just assume that I need to trust someone if I use their package.  The package install process is still running as `root` :-).