# What is the scope of a public key added by apt-key?

Tags: apt, package-management

I was wondering whether a public key added by `apt-key` is

- per repository (all packages in a repository are authenticated with the same public key) or
- per package (different packages in the same repository may be authenticated with different public keys).

In other words, what does a public key authenticate: a package, a repository, or something else?

The manpage of `apt-key` says

> apt-key is used to manage the list of keys used by apt to authenticate **packages**. Packages
>   which have been authenticated using these keys will be considered trusted.
>
> ...
>   It is critical that keys added manually via apt-key are verified to belong to the owner of
>   **the repositories** they claim to be for.

For example, I was wondering why there is no repository or something else specified as a scope to which a public key is applicable to?

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463140/135943

Answer (score 4):

Keys themselves aren’t scoped at all: any key added to the `apt` keyring is considered a valid signature key.

In Debian-style repositories, the signature applies to the whole repository: each repository’s `Release` file is signed, either as a detached signature (`Release.gpg`) or inline (`InRelease`). The signature indicates which key was used to sign the file (or which keys, since a file can be signed by multiple keys). Everything else is verified using information in the `Release` file. See [How is the authenticity of Debian packages guaranteed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285635/86440) for details.

If you want to specify which keys should be used to verify a given repository, you can do that in the repository description in `sources.list`, not when adding the key to `apt`’s keyring; see the `Signed-By` option in [the `sources.list` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/sources.list.5).

Comment: How does apt know which added key is used for authenticate which package from which repository? We can add many public keys in an apt-key command. In the example, when adding a public key, why is its scope not specified?

Comment: See the update.