# Unable to use any third party repos on Debian 10

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, docker, gpg

I am having an issue on Debian 10 using any sort of third party repo. I want to install both Docker and ZeroTier One, but I am getting a similar issue trying to use both repos.

In the case of ZeroTier, thier website instructs me to use the command `curl -s https://install.zerotier.com | sudo bash`. After doing that, and trying to run `apt-update` I am met with the following:

```
Err:4 http://download.zerotier.com/debian/buster buster InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1657198823E52A61
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.zerotier.com/debian/buster buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1657198823E52A61
E: The repository 'http://download.zerotier.com/debian/buster buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

In the case of Docker, I have followed the the instructions directly from their website which can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/). When I try to run `apt-get update` I am met with the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've read through the `apt-secure` manpage and tried just about every solution I can find online, but to no avail. Someone please help me!

Comment: Both of these sets of instructions either advise to use, or include in scripts, `apt-key add`.  This is not the source of the problem in this particular case, but anyone reading this should bear in mind that both Docker and ZeroTier have insecure repository installation mechanisms that introduce a well-known vulnerability onto users' systems, which was addressed by Debian in 2017.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463140/5132

Answer (score 0):

If Debian has GPG (*gpg*) installed, a more secure option for installing ZeroTier One is available:

```
curl -s 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/master/doc/contact%40zerotier.com.gpg' | gpg --import && \
if z=$(curl -s 'https://install.zerotier.com/' | gpg); then echo "$z" | sudo bash; fi
```

After running the script, use apt to manage future updates to zerotier-one.

---

The line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that says `https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \Release` is not correct.

- Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Comment out the incorrect line in sources.list by preceding it with a `#` character.
- Save the change made to sources.list and update the software sources with `sudo apt update`.

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

> Before you install Docker Engine for the first time on a new host
> machine, you need to set up the Docker repository. Afterward, you can
> install and update Docker from the repository.
>
> 1. Update the `apt` package index and install packages to allow `apt` to use a repository over HTTPS:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt install \
>        apt-transport-https \
>        ca-certificates \
>        curl \
>        gnupg-agent \
>        software-properties-common
>    ```
> 2. Add Docker’s official GPG key:
>
>    ```
>    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
>    ```
>
>    Verify that you now have the key with the fingerprint`9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88`, by searching for the last 8
>    characters of the fingerprint.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
>
>    pub   4096R/0EBFCD88 2017-02-22
>          Key fingerprint = 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
>    uid                  Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
>    sub   4096R/F273FCD8 2017-02-22
>    ```
> 3. Use the following commands to set up the **stable** repository.
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository \
>       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
>       $(lsb_release -cs) \
>       stable"
>    sudo apt update
>    ```

<sup>**Source:** [Install Docker Engine on Debian | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)</sup>