# How can I add a repository in a more useful way?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, repository

I try to install VirtualBox in ubuntu 18.04, following https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

> Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list. According to
>   your distribution, replace '' with 'artful', 'zesty',
>   'yakkety', 'xenial', 'trusty', 'stretch', 'jessie', or 'wheezy' (older
>   versions of VirtualBox supported different distributions):
>
> ```
> deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib
> ```

1. Here is my command:

   ```
   sudo echo "deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Is there some programitcal way to get the value of `<mydist>`
   instead of filling `bionic` in? I want to make it reusable for all
   Ubuntu versions.
2. Also if I add the line to an individual file instead of
   `/etc/apt/sources.list`, how shall I name the file?

   - Do I need to make the filename unique so that I will not overwrite an existing file? Ho?
   - [The purpose of individual file is for scripting to check existence of a repository or remove an existing repository.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407328/what-is-the-benefit-of-etc-apt-sources-list-d-over-etc-apt-sources-list) So is it
     correct that an arbitrary filename isn't okay? For
     example:

     ```
     echo "deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/my.virtualbox.list
     ```

Thanks.

Comment: As for your last point of 2, it is a convention. So in principle, even if it is your convention,  it should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On Ubuntu, `lsb_release -sc` will give you the codename corresponding to the installed release.
2. If you use a filename which is already in use, and the `>` redirection operator, you will overwrite the existing file, yes.

   For single-line repository descriptors, filenames must end with `.list`. See [the `sources.list` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/sources.list) for details. Apart from that you can use any name you like, as long as it uses only alphanumeric characters, underscores, hyphens, and periods. If you want to check for a file’s existence, you know the name you want to use; there’s no official registry of repository filenames.

Comment: Thanks. Shall I overwrite when it is possible? If not, how can I avoid overwriting?

Comment: What problem are you trying to avoid? A `virtualbox.list` file is unlikely to be used for anything other than the VirtualBox repository, so overwriting it is fine IMO.